# Continue on the next else if if value is not true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have written a code that checks some conditions.

But i got stumble on this part. I have used the `continue;` but it doesn't run and says it has an error.

```
if (support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null){

    if ((arrayIndex.length - 1) === arrayIndex.lastIndexOf("FIXED")){

      var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "FIXED");

    }else if ((dataTwo.length - 1) !== dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED")){

      continue; <-- This doesn't work.if this part of IF is true i want it to 
                    jump to the next else if

    }


}else if (check_PinnedSupports.BoleanValue === "Existing"){   <----jump here

  var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");

}
```

Comment: What is suppose to do inside this `else if ((dataTwo.length - 1) !== dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED"))`

Comment: `continue` is used to skip the rest of the body of a loop and skip to the next iteration in said loop - it has nothing to do with if/else

Comment: to check if (dataTwo.length - 1) !== dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED") is true. is this possible that in this section id like it to have a command to jump to the other else if? cause continue doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`break` and `continue` statements are to be used in `loops` and not in `if-else` blocks.
You should rather merge the statements using logical operators

```
if ((support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null) && ((arrayIndex.length - 1) === arrayIndex.lastIndexOf("FIXED"))){

  var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "FIXED");

} else if (check_PinnedSupports.BoleanValue === "Existing" || ((support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null) && ((dataTwo.length - 1) !== dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED")))){

  var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");

}
```

Using the `||` operator (`OR`) will solve your issue.

**EDIT**
If you do not mind some redundancy in your code but want it to look cleaner, just repeat the variable's value assignment instead of `continue`

```
if (support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null){

    if ((arrayIndex.length - 1) === arrayIndex.lastIndexOf("FIXED")){

      var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "FIXED");

    }else if ((dataTwo.length - 1) !== dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED")){

      var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");

    }


}else if (check_PinnedSupports.BoleanValue === "Existing"){   <----jump here

  var supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");

}
```

Comment: right yeah good point mate i didn't thought of this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid repeated conditionals and repeated code is possible using a little known javascript construct ... the `label`

depending on what `jump here` is actually referring to (before the if, or the body of the if)

So, before the if (so the last if is checked regardless)

```
var supportFBnode_index;
hack: {
    if (support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null) {
        if ((arrayIndex.length - 1) === arrayIndex.lastIndexOf("FIXED")){
            supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "FIXED");
            break hack; // DO NOT RUN THE LAST IF
        } else if ((dataTwo.length - 1) === dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED")) { // changed to === so, if !==, next if gets run
            break hack; // DO NOT RUN THE LAST IF
        }
    }
    // the jump in your code refers to this point
    if (check_PinnedSupports.BoleanValue === "Existing") {
        supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");
    }
}
```

or, body of the if, i.e. the code inside the last if is the destination for the jump

```
var supportFBnode_index;
hack: {
    if (support_Fixednodes !== undefined && support_Fixednodes !== null) {
        if ((arrayIndex.length - 1) === arrayIndex.lastIndexOf("FIXED")) {
            supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "FIXED");
            break hack; // DO NOT RUN THE LAST ASSIGNMENT
        } else if ((dataTwo.length - 1) === dataTwo.lastIndexOf("FIXED")) { // changed to === to skip last bit
            break hack; // DO NOT RUN THE LAST ASSIGNMENT
        }
    } else if (check_PinnedSupports.BoleanValue !== "Existing") { // changed to !== to skip last bit
        break hack; // DO NOT RUN THE LAST ASSIGNMENT
    }
    // the jump in your code refers to this point
    supportFBnode_index = checkIfElementExist(dataTwo, "PINNED");
}
```

So, instead of jumping to a point in the code if a condition is met, we can `break` past it if the condition is not met

Note the `var supportFBnode_index;` declaration - while having `var supportFBnode_index =` in two places works, it's not best practice (especially if you later change var to let) ... so that's a freebie hint :p

---

simple `break label` example

```js
hack: {
  console.log('this will output');
  break hack;
  console.log('this wont output');
}
console.log('done');
```

basically, `break label` causes execution to skip the rest of the labelled block

As I said, a little known feature of the language, but it has its place - though, I'm sure there are other ways to avoid "repetition" in this case, but this, to me, is the most elegant